# I am not able to understand code for index function as well as add_to_cart function in views.py file while designing an ecomm website

Tags: django

This is all the code that I want to understand deeply that what's going on underneath the hood.
This code lies in views.py file and I am designing an ecommerce website in django using python 2.7 version. I have Cart, Product and Item Model on models.py file.
Also my project name is ShoppingCart and app name is shopping.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import View
from shopping.models import Cart, Product, Item
import string
import random

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    user = request.user
    items = ''
    if user.is_anonymous():
        user = ''
    else:
        items = Item.ojects.filter(cart__user=user, cart__checked_out=False)
        items = items.count() if items else 0
    products = Product.objects.filter(total_items__get=0)

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'products':products, 'user':user, 'items':items, 'page':'home'})

def add_to_cart(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_anonymous():
        chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
        user_name = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(9))
        password = '1234567a'
        user = User.objects.create(username=user_name, first_name='guest', last_name='guest', 
        email='guest@gmail.com', is_active=True is_staff=True)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        user = authenticate(username=user_name, password=password)
        if user:
            login(request.user)

    product_id = request.GET.get('product_id')
    cart = Cart.objects.filter(checked_out=False, user=user)
    cart = cart[0] if cart else ''
    if not cart:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(user=user)
    Item.objects.create(cart=cart, product_id=product_id, quantity=1)
    return redirect('index')
```

Comment: Are you facing any particular problem or just want to know what the code does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I understand:

The **index** view says: If the user is not anonymous -> return him particular values from database (cart_user equals to current user and checked_out value is False), then count items and return with "products" (which total_item value are 0)

The **add_to_cart** view basically again checks for user authentication, and if user is anonymous, it creates a user with random username, password, mail then gets product_id from the HTML form and adds 1 item quantity of this product for user in database.

I hope it will help you. Good luck!

Comment: I'm having confusion in understanding the function of two users. Please explain in some detail and also tell that what is anonymous user?

Comment: @NishchalGupta, What do you mean by **function of two users**? Anonymous user means that current user is **not** logged in.